# Creating manual threads, also tried using parallel.foreach and async await - but getting duplicate

Tags: c#, multithreading

ISSUE: Getting duplicate items, i.e more threads are getting created than the array size... 
Hi Folks, I am creating thread in the loop for each element of array. The real use is that the of sending a batch of messages using amazon ses. the messages are stored in the messageamazonRequestBatch and the loop runs through the batch and sends the messages.

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
Thread thrdSendEmail;
try
{
    string amazonMessageID = string.Empty;
    List<Thread> lstThread = new List<Thread>();
    foreach (int n in arrMessageid)
    {
        thrdSendEmail = new Thread(() =>
        {
                try
                {
                    amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).req);
                    messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).msg.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                    logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n , true);
                    //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n + ",\t" + messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).msg.QueueMessageId + ",\t" + amazonMessageID, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true); }                                
        });
        thrdSendEmail.Name = n.ToString();
        lstThread.Add(thrdSendEmail);
        thrdSendEmail.Start();
        //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n, true);
    }
    foreach (Thread t in lstThread)
    {
        t.Join();
        //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + t.Name, true);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true);
}
```

I have also tried parallel.foreach and asynch and await options... they also give the duplicates. I know that the lock will solve the problem but in my case the lock degrades the performance by a factor of 10.. that is my performance drops 10 times... coz putting the sendemail login in lock is blocking untill i get a return amazonmessageid from amazon...

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. I am not a novice programmer but new to threading...my contact email is shabbirbohra@gmail.com

ALSO TRIED MANY VERSION OF PARALLEL.foreach

```
private int SendEmailTask_Ver9_23Jan()//tried to create manual threads in parallel foreach and called SendSimpleEmail_Part3 but still duplicates
{
    activeThreadCount++; threadCount++;
    IList<Airmail.Core.Message> messageBatch = null;
    lock (dbLocker)
    {
        if (activeThreadCount > maxNoofTaskCount)//targetThreadCount
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (abort)
        {
            sendComplete = true;
            return 0;
        }
        try
        {
            messageBatch = messageRepository.ash_GetNextBatch_AirmailVer2(maxBatchSize, this.senderTrackingHost);//messageBatch = messageRepository.ash_GetNextBatch(maxBatchSize);                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logManager_RunSummary.LogException(ex);
            messageBatch = new List<Airmail.Core.Message>();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(this.currentStatus);
    }
    while (messageBatch != null && messageBatch.Count != 0)
    {
        IDictionary<Airmail.Core.Message, MessageHistory> toUpdate = new Dictionary<Airmail.Core.Message, MessageHistory>();
        batchSize = messageBatch.Count;
        sendComplete = false;
        //foreach (Airmail.Core.Message message in messageBatch)                
        logManager_CollectionLog.LogMessage("\tBatch\t-\t" + messageBatch.Count + "\t-\t" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, true);//ASH-TEST 11Jan14
        int intCounter = 0;//ash-teset 11han14
        System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<Airmail.Core.Message> messageBatchConcurrent = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<Airmail.Core.Message>(messageBatch);
        //All public and protected members of ConcurrentBag<T> are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.
        //foreach (Airmail.Core.Message message in messageBatchConcurrent)
        Parallel.ForEach(messageBatchConcurrent, message =>                
        {
            //messageBatchConcurrent.Where(x => x == message).Take(1);//ash12Jan14
            lock (statLocker)
            {
                //messageBatchConcurrent.TryTake(out message);
                totalProcessed++;
                intCounter += 1;//ASH-TEST 10Jan14                    
                message.ash_BatchLoopCounter = intCounter.ToString();
                //message.ash_BatchSizeCount = messageBatchConcurrent.Count.ToString();
            }
            if (message.ExpiryDate < DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                toUpdate.Add(message, message.UpdateStatus(MessageStatus.Expired, "", null, null, true));
                //message.continue(); //continue;//continue will just skip the current iteration.
                return; //using return instead of continue as --> (the body is just a function called for each item)
            }

            lock (statLocker)
            {
                StatisticKey key = new StatisticKey(Convert.ToInt32(message.ash_campaignHistoryID), Convert.ToInt32(message.ash_campaignTemplateID), message.Status);//ASH25,OCT13//Airmail 2.0 changes
                if (!statistics.ContainsKey(key)) statistics.Add(key, 0);
                statistics[key]--;
            }
            try
            {

                string amazonMessageID = string.Empty;
                if (message.Attachments == null || message.Attachments == "")//ASH25,OCT13//Airmail 2.0 changes
                {
                    //test//if (intCounter > 1000) { Debugger.Break(); }
                    SendEmailResponse response = null;
                    if (message.ash_isSent == "YES") { return; }
                    //if (message.ash_isSent == null) { response = SendSimpleEmail(ref message, message.QueueMessageId, message.ash_BatchLoopCounter + "-" + message.ash_BatchSizeCount, message.ash_isSent); }//ASH-TEST 11Jan14                           
                    /// Start - this is parallel.invoke testing on 23Jan14
                    try
                    {
                        //Parallel.Invoke(
                        //    delegate()        // Param #2 - in-line delegate
                        //    {
                        //mReq.msg.AmazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2((SendEmailRequest)mReq.req);
                        //logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage(",\t" + mReq.msg.QueueMessageId, true);
                        //    }
                        //);
                        //intthreadCount++;
                        //logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage(",\t creating new thread", true);
                        Thread thrdSendEmail = new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            if (message.ash_isSent == null) { response = SendSimpleEmail_Part3(message, message.QueueMessageId, message.ash_BatchLoopCounter + "-" + message.ash_BatchSizeCount, message.ash_isSent); }
                        });
                        lock (statLocker)
                        {
                            thrdSendEmail.Start();                                    
                        }
                        thrdSendEmail.Join();
                        //logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage(",\t finishing new thread", true);
                    }
                    // No exception is expected in this example, but if one is still thrown from a task, 
                    // it will be wrapped in AggregateException and propagated to the main thread. 
                    catch (AggregateException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An action has thrown an exception. THIS WAS UNEXPECTED.\n{0}", e.InnerException.ToString());
                    }
                    /// End -   this is parallel.invoke testing on 23Jan14                            
                    //SendRawEmailResponse response = SendRawEmail(message);

                    //cSH12Jan14-test//sqlLogSentMessage += "EXEC ash_Log_SentMessageids  " + "@MessageID = " + message.QueueMessageId + ", " + "@Identifier = '" + message.Identifier.ToString() + "', " + "@AmazonMessageID = '" + message.AmazonMessageID + "', " + "@Status = " + ((int)message.Status).ToString() + ", " + "@ToEmailAddress = '" + message.To.Address + "', " + "@CreatedDate = '" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + "'\n";
                    //logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage( ",\t" + message.ash_BatchLoopCounter + "-" + message.ash_BatchSizeCount +  ",\t" + response.SendEmailResult.MessageId + ",\t" + message.QueueMessageId, true);//ASH-TEST 11Jan14
                    lock (statLocker)
                    {
                        if (response != null) amazonMessageID = response.SendEmailResult.MessageId;
                        if (message.ash_isSent == "DUPLICATE") { return; }
                    }
                    //logManager_CollectionLog.LogMessage("\tSendSimpleEmail\t-\t" + message.ash_BatchSizeCount + "-" + message.ash_BatchLoopCounter + "\t-\t" + message.QueueMessageId, true);//ASH-TEST 10Jan14                            
                }
                else
                {
                    SendRawEmailResponse response = SendRawEmail(message);
                    lock (statLocker)
                    {
                        if (response != null) amazonMessageID = response.SendRawEmailResult.MessageId;
                        intCounter += 1;//ASH-TEST 10Jan14
                        logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage("\tSendRawEmail-1" + intCounter + "\t-\t" + amazonMessageID + "\t-\t" + message.QueueMessageId, true);//ASH-TEST 10Jan14
                    }
                }
                lock (statLocker)
                {
                    message.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                    toUpdate.Add(message, message.UpdateStatus(amazonMessageID == string.Empty ? MessageStatus.Tested : MessageStatus.Sent,
                                                                "", null, null, true));
                    messageCount++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("blacklist")
                 || ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("rejected")
                 || ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("not verified")
                 || ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("illegal")
                    //|| message.OldStatus == MessageStatus.Failed)
                 || message.Status == MessageStatus.Failed)
                {
                    toUpdate.Add(message, message.UpdateStatus(MessageStatus.Undeliverable, ex.Message, null, null, true));
                }
                else
                {
                    toUpdate.Add(message, message.UpdateStatus(MessageStatus.Failed, ex.Message, null, null, true));
                }
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToLower());//ASH22Nov
            }
            lock (statLocker)
            {
                StatisticKey key = new StatisticKey(Convert.ToInt32(message.ash_campaignHistoryID), Convert.ToInt32(message.ash_campaignTemplateID), message.Status);//ASH25,OCT13//Airmail 2.0 changes
                if (!statistics.ContainsKey(key)) statistics.Add(key, 0);
                statistics[key]++;
            }
        });
        lock (dbLocker)
        {
            //cSH12Jan14-test//messageRepository.ash_Log_SentMessageids(sqlLogSentMessage);//ASH12Jan14
            try
            {
                Task UpdateMessages_Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => messageRepository.ash_UpdateMessages(toUpdate), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                UpdateMessages_Task.Wait();//ASH18Sep2013 - This task added for updating message asynchronously
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logManager_RunSummary.LogException(ex);
            }
            if (activeThreadCount > maxNoofTaskCount)//targetThreadCount
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (abort)
            {
                sendComplete = true;
                return 1;
            }
            try
            {
                if (messageBatch == null && messageBatch.Count == 0)
                {
                    messageBatch = messageRepository.ash_GetNextBatch_AirmailVer2(maxBatchSize, this.senderTrackingHost);//messageBatch = messageRepository.ash_GetNextBatch(maxBatchSize);
                }
                else { messageBatch = null; }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logManager_RunSummary.LogException(ex);
                messageBatch = new List<Airmail.Core.Message>();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(this.currentStatus);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an "Access to modified closure" problem.  Look into that for more details.  There's a lot of examples of what it is.

Simple fix is to store your n variable in a temp variable everywhere you use it in your delegate.

```
foreach (int n in arrMessageid)
    {
        int tempN = n;
        Thread thrdSendEmail = new Thread(() =>
        {
                try
                {
                    amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(tempN ).req);
                    messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(tempN ).msg.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                    logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + tempN  , true);
                    //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + tempN  + ",\t" + messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(tempN ).msg.QueueMessageId + ",\t" + amazonMessageID, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true); }                                
        });
        thrdSendEmail.Name = n.ToString();
        lstThread.Add(thrdSendEmail);
        thrdSendEmail.Start();
        //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n, true);
    }
```

Comment: Hi TTat, I tried your suggestion but it is still giving me duplicates.

Comment: Which part contains the duplicate?

Comment: the log -logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID contains the duplicate as well as the messages-SendSimpleEmail_Part2 are received as duplicates.

Comment: i tried this code..                            while (i < messageAmazonRequestBatch.Count)
                            {
                                int iloop = i;
                                Message_withRequest mr = messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(iloop);
                                actions.Add(() => messageAmazonRequestBatch[iloop] = SendSimpleEmail_Part10(mr));
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        foreach (var act in actions)
                        {
                            act.Invoke();}

Comment: that also gives duplicates and kill speed - here is remaining code..         private Message_withRequest SendSimpleEmail_Part10(Message_withRequest mr)
        {

            try
            {
                mr.msg.AmazonMessageID = ses.SendEmail(mr.req).SendEmailResult.MessageId;//"";
                logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage(",\t" + mr.msg.QueueMessageId + "\t" + mr.msg.AmazonMessageID, true);
                return mr;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logManager_RunSummary.LogException(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

Comment: Is n giving you a duplicate?  Are you sure all values in arrMessageid are unique?  Are you modifying arrMessageid anywhere else in your thread?

Comment: yes n is giving duplicate and i am sure all values in arrMEssageid are unique and no, i am not modifying arrMessageid anywhere else in the thread at all.

Comment: Can you show the code for this method?  logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage().  Is it thread safe?

Comment: here it is TTat... public class LogManager_NoConsole
{
private StreamWriter logStream;
        public void LogMessage(string message, bool significant)
        {
            try{
            if (significant) IsEmpty = false;
            logStream.WriteLine(message);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
        public void LogEnd()
        {
            logStream.Close();
        }
}

Comment: StreamWriter is NOT thread safe.  I suspect there isn't a problem with nTemp.  Put a lock on logStream in your logger and see if there are still duplicates.  Another test you can do is use a thread safe Collection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx) and add nTemp to the collection in the thread.  Then check if there are duplicates by putting a break point at the end of the method.

Comment: Sure, I will try that and will update you.. Thanks a lot TTat, your kind help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hi TTat, The logmanager has stopped giving duplicate when i put it in the lock.. but the issue is if i put the logmanager in lock, i dont get duplicates in log but it still sends duplicate now which i am not having any control of... so if i write 2 logs, one with lock and other without, i dont see duplicate in locked log but i see it in unlocked lock.. As i told you i can't lock the sending part which is ses.SendEmail(mr.req) coz it slows me down 10 times... so is there any workaround to it..

Comment: List<Func<Message_withRequest>> actions = new List<Func<Message_withRequest>>();
                try
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        while (i < messageAmazonRequestBatch.Count)
                        {
                            int iloop = i;
                            Message_withRequest mr = messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(iloop);
                            actions.Add(() => messageAmazonRequestBatch[iloop] = SendSimpleEmail_Part11(mr));
                            i++;

Comment: }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true);
                    }
                    Parallel.ForEach ( actions, act =>
                    {
                        Func<Message_withRequest> f = act;
                        f.Invoke();
                    });
                }         //this is the final code now...

Comment: So that confirms it's a threading issue in your methods and not the loop itself.  No matter what you will need to lock your critical resource if you're sharing it across threads.  If you want to avoid locking it, they will each need to have their own copy of the resource.  Usually the goal is to spend as little time as possible in the critical section so you don't have threads wasting time just waiting on the resource when it could be doing other processing.  I suggest you do some more reading on multithreading and shared resources.

Comment: Without seeing your sendemail code, I'm assuming you're sharing something there across threads.  Is that necessary?  Multithreading is very tricky and unpredictable when you have shared resources with multiple readers and writers.

Comment: Hi TTat, Sendemail is an amazon webservice. If there is an issue there, i can raise it with them. But here the issue is that i am getting more threads thying to callsendemail somehow getting same message referance.. is that possible, if yes, how can i stop it without using the lock.

Comment: If SendEmail is an Amazon Webservice, you will need to find out if it's ThreadSafe.  If it's not ThreadSafe (something I'm sure is the case), then you will need to lock it.  There really isn't a way around that.  The reason why there's duplicates is your threads are getting Context Switched out after it set the message, and before it sends the message.  A lock prevents that.

Comment: Hi TTat, I have asked if sendSimpleEmail is thread safe from Amazon and waiting for their reply. I just need to understand why compiler creates more thread than required, this is the cause of duplicate. With lock the parallelism almost disappear and it becomes serial again... thats like loosing out on the benefits of parallelism.. Can you shade more light on why context switch is happening here coz their is no shared variables at all... really confused why?

Comment: Also i tried a different approach where i added a bool property to the message called isSent.. so i wrote lock(s){msg.isSent = true;) and then wrote if(msg.isSent == true){sendSimpleEmail(msg);}... this also creating duplicate... why is this happening, this can only happen if lock is not working properly...

Comment: It's NOT creating more threads than required.  You're just not understanding how multi threading works.  I highly suggest you read up more on multi threading since it is now beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Hi TTat, Thanks for your help. However, I have a question here, if it is not creating more threads than why does a function called more than expected no. of times. is it not true that If only it is calling more than expected no. of times that i am getting more messages and if i lock it, the count is correct and if i unlock it the count is always greater..?

Comment: Without knowing the internals of the send email code, it's hard to save exactly.  But if it was a situation where there's a goes send -> acknowledge -> resend if no acknowledge, it can look like it sent multiple times.  And your log already confirms there isn't more threads.  Your thread is doing 2 things: send email and log.  If there were more threads running, you would see your log have more entries too.  But you have already confirmed that's not the case when you have the writer locked so that it's thread safe.

Comment: Hi TTat, so do you mean to say that my code is full proof now and only thing i need to worry about is the sendsimpleemail function from amazon.. I havent yet go their reply on that. As far as log is concerned, you are correct that i dont get log duplicate when locked however do get duplicate when not locked... to correct problem with amazon send, i wrote the code again so that the amazon code does not execute by duplicate thread..

Comment: so i wrote lock(s){if (msg.isSent == null? true: false) and then wrote this code without lock
 if(msg.isSent == true){sendSimpleEmail(msg);}... 
this also creating duplicate... why is this happening,

Comment: I tried using 2 sempahore object --> objSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);objSemaphore2 = new Semaphore(2, 8); --> then wrote below code   -->                             Message_withRequest mr;
objSemaphore.WaitOne();
  msgBatCC.TryTake(out mr);
  mr.msg.ash_isSent = mr.msg.ash_isSent == null ? "Yes" : "Duplicate";
objSemaphore.Release();
objSemaphore2.WaitOne();
if (mr.msg.ash_isSent == "Yes")
                {
                    mr.msg.AmazonMessageID = ses.SendEmail(mr.req).SendEmailResult.MessageId;
                    }

Comment: now if i declare objSemaphore2 = new Semaphore(1, 1); then i get no duplicates however the more max size i increase of this for example objSemaphore2 = new Semaphore(2, 8); the more duplicates i get and so on.... can you suggest something by using semaphore..

Comment: Hi Guys, I am still awaiting the amazon response. I have doubt that the amazon function is not threadsafe as after doing all precautions. implementing producer, consumer logic also i am getting duplicates.